# How can I give psql a variable instead of an sql file as input?

Tags: bash, sql, postgresql

So I have some sql in a varible.
I could put that in a file and give it to psql as input but I wonder if there is an easy way to do this without the file ?

Comment: Can you add some more detail please?  Maybe some information about how the variable was filled, what with, what you want it to do, what language you're working in, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can either pipe the command to psql

```
echo "$some_sql_in_a_varible" | psql -d mydatabase
```

or use `-c`

```
psql -d database -c "$some_sql_in_a_varibl"
```

Mor info on [the psql man page](http://www.rootr.net/man/man/psql/1)